# Combine two or more servers to stream a file. Possible?

Tags: multithreading, flash, streaming, video-streaming

I'm working on a project of a streaming website dedicated to the South American public. Traffic in South America is super expensive, for example Hostdime charges $500 for each 4TB transferred. I would pay $12500 alone to use 100TB, besides the price of the server.

Servers here in the US can only push about 250Kb/s ~ 350Kb/s to Brazil. That is not enough to stream HD videos, so I thought:

Let's suppose I have 4 servers in Miami. If each server was able to stream to Brazil at 200Kb/s, if I combine the 4 servers to do one stream I would get 800Kb/s, which is pretty good to stream HD videos.

Is it possible to do this? It would save us a whole bunch of money and time. And it would be cheaper than use a CDN too. The lowest price we've found was CDN.net, which charges $0.13 for each GB transferred from Brazil.

I managed to do get a similar approach using a download accelerator. I put one file in 4 servers, and used flashget to download the file from one server. It detected the other 3 servers and divided the download in small chunks, and downloaded simultaneously from the 4 servers, just like torrents. I was able to achieve 1000Kb/s on a link of 10Mbps. Before using this, the max speed was around 350Kb/s... (I was using a remote desktop in Brazil, downloading from servers in NY).

I want to do this to stream videos to my clients, they won't need to download them. And this is where it gets complicated. I guess this would be impossible to do using HTML5. But there's still Flash..

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In short no, it is not possible to split video files into multiple streams and reconstitute them in ActionScript. HTML5 and Javascript are also out of the question with regards to this method.

In the contrast, I would recommend that you investigate other options.

- Considering the high cost of server renting, perhaps you could provide your own server and colocate for less.
- [CloudFront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) from Amazon has edge servers located in São Paulo, Brazil. Perhaps this could provide a more cost friendly solution than other providers?
- Finally, it might be possible to increase throughput by tweaking your web server. I recommend utilizing [nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/Main) or increasing the buffers to better accomodate the transfer of HD videos.
- Don't forget to benchmark. Just because one solution may appear faster doesn't mean that it will be that way for your visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Check out BitTorrent Sync. I'm looking at their API right now, it looks like there might be something there for you.